# Why was the web service task canceled and how do I find out?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

When I'm trying to log in to my website using an online web service I wrote, I don't see anything happening at all...

I should point out that this works 100% when I run everything from localhost.

In my login:

```
    private async Task DoLogin(string EmailAddress, string Password)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ServiceURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            User u = new User() { EmailAddress = EmailAddress, Password = Password };

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/user/login", u);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                u = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<User>();
                if (u.Role.RoleName == "Admin")
                {
                    generateCookie(u);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Your user account is not permitted to access this website");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The email address or password you entered is incorrect.");
            }
        }
    }
```

During execution, this doesn't get past the `PostAsJsonAsync` await although I get a response (as taken from Fiddler):

> {"Title":"USER LOGIN","Message":"Error actioning request: [ A task was
>   canceled.
>   ]\r\n","Error":"System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task
>   was canceled.\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   OrtundAdmin.Controllers.HomeController.\u003cDoLogin\u003ed__4.MoveNext()
>   in r:\Users\Logan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Backup\OrtundService\OrtundAdmin\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line
>   66\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   OrtundAdmin.Controllers.HomeController.\u003cLogin\u003ed__0.MoveNext()
>   in r:\Users\Logan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Backup\OrtundService\OrtundAdmin\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line
>   38"}

This formatting tells me that something went wrong on the service (see the HttpPost below) but it's very vague - "task was canceled". Why? How do I find out?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("~/api/user/login")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody]User Source)
    {
        try
        {
            User requestedUser = db.Users.Include("Role").FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmailAddress == Source.EmailAddress);

            if (requestedUser != null && Hashing.ValidatePassword(Source.Password, requestedUser.Password))
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, requestedUser);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Incorrect username or password");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ReportError(ex, "USER LOGIN");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should probably put a try catch around the code in the service call and log / debug whatever exception is being thrown to determine what in your code is failing. The Async on the service method is going to hide the real exception from you so you need to debug inside the service to find out what's really happening.

Comment: @CodeUniquely when I was testing my web app locally, connecting it to the live web service, I used Fiddler4 to see what was going on. At first I got an error saying the web service couldn't connect to the database, but now I'm not getting anything

Comment: I tend to find that I get nothing back from Async calls even when there are exceptions in the code. The exception does not make it past the return into the calling code it just seems to get swallowed. When i put a try catch block inside the service and break point inside the  catch - low and behold exceptions are firing  - just a thought